# Write output of ZIO Stream to file

Tags: scala, zio, zio-streams

I am trying to write the results of a ZIO Stream to a file. The following example app takes a sequence of integers, converts them to bytes, compresses them with the gzip transducer, but I cannot figure out how to write them to a file.

I think I need to use `ZSink.fromOutputStream`, but I am unsure how that fits into the code.

```
object ZStreamExample extends zio.App {
  val job = (for {
    stream <- ZStream
      .fromIterable(Seq(1,2,3,4))
      .map(value => s"$value")
      .map(value => value.toByte)
      .transduce(gzip())
  } yield stream)

  def run(args: List[String]) = {
    job.runCollect
  }.exitCode
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to take a closer look to the [**docs**](https://zio.dev/version-1.x/datatypes/stream/zstream#consuming-a-stream) and the [**api**](https://javadoc.io/doc/dev.zio/zio-streams_2.13/latest/zio/stream/ZSink$.html).

It seems you only need to do something like this:

```
object ZStreamExample extends zio.App {
  val job =
    ZStream
      .fromIterable(Seq(1,2,3,4))
      .map(value => s"$value")
      .map(value => value.toByte)
      .transduce(gzip())
      .run(ZSink.fromFile(Paths.get("file.txt")))

  def run(args: List[String]) =
    job.exitCde
}
```

Comment: The docs are clear, but I just missed the `fromFile` method.